# fatal error: sdl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, sdl

I'm having some issues getting a CHIP-8 interpreter to compile.
Upon pressing ctrl+f9 to compile I am met by a message saying "Build ended with errors. Continue?".

Checking the build log reveals the following error: C:/Workspace/****/****/main.c:4:17: fatal error: sdl.h: No such file or directory

I have tried copying SDL.h into the source directory, that did not work.

I tried making a directory in source called "SDL" (src/SDL/SDL.h), did not work.

I also tried making a folder next to src, (SDL/SDL.h). That did not work either.

After that I tried #include <.SDL.h>, #include <.sdl.h>, #include <.SDL.dll> and #include <.sdl.dll> (ignore the period after the "<" symbol)

I have also tried copying over the files for SDL version 1.2.15 and SDL version 2.0.3. That did work either.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?
How do I get this to compile?

Comment: Thank you Bastien Durel for your quick response.

Comment: How did you install SDL in your system? Is it a windows or linux? which IDE?

Comment: I downloaded SDL, I don't understand how to install it. I am running windows 10, technical preview and the IDE I am using is CodeLite
I tried adding -I/C:/Users/****/Desktop/SDL-1.2.15/include/SDL to the list of switch statements, but it does not appear to be working.
The compiler I am using is MinGW ( TDM-GCC-32 )

Comment: I added the path in the include statement and now it is no longer throwing the error stating that it was not found. Just a whole lot more, different errors. I am going to try SDL2 and see if it does the same thing.

Comment: Its not the problem with SDL1.2.5. Its problem with configuration. SDL2 won't help you with that either.

Comment: SDL2 throws less errors, so I started replacing bits of code with NULL to see if I could get it to compile. Upon typing my second NULL, codelite proceeded to lock up.
Should I just give up and go back to FreeBasic?

Answer (score 1):

You have to say your compiler where sdl.h lives, with `-I/path/to/sdl` switch on gcc or filling `Include Path` in msvc

(don't move it, as it (sdl.h) will probably needs other header files)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a step-by-step on how to get SDL1.2.5 working with codelite:

1. Download the "Development Libraries" from [here](https://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php)
2. Extract the tar.gz file contents to a directory. For eg: `C:\mysdl`
3. In codelite, right-click over the project's name in the "Workspace View"
4. From the context menu, select "Settings..."
5. The 'Project Settings' dialog will appear.
6. In the "configuration Type" choose "Debug" or "Release", based on your requirements. You can also, do the following steps for both Debug and Release.

   - Go to "Compiler" tab

     - In "Additional Search Path", add the path where all the sdl include files are. For eg: `C:\mysdl\include`
   - Go to "Linker" tab

     - In "Library Path", add you lib path eg: `C:\mysdl\lib\`
     - In the "Options" append `-lSDL -lSDLmain -lmingw32 -mwindows`(case-matters)
7. Copy `C:\mysdl\bin\SDL.dll` to `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32` or if 64-bit `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`
8. When including headers you must use `#include "SDL\SDL.h"` or `#include "SDL.h"` depending on how you configure your directory structure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this person doesn't use Codelite.